# Second latest folder in a Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want a batch file which will find out which is the second latest folder created/modified in a directory.
I found this article but no matter how much i tried i could not understand how it works

```
@echo off

set "root_dir=c:\somewhere"
pushd "%root_dir%"
set "bl1="
set "bl2="
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:d') do (
set "bl2=!bl1!"
set "bl1=%%#"
)
echo %bl2%
endlocal
```

If i use it as it is then i can get the second latest folder but this script is supposedly able to get which ever latest folder you need , be it 1st or nth.
Could someone please tell me what modifications need to be done to the script to accomplish that. Also how exactly this script works

Comment: I assume you are still working with **MS-DOS**, the OS from the 1980s, as you tagged your question with [tag:dos], don't you? anyway, the latest folder is already contained in variable `bl1` -- add `echo %bl1%` to display it... retrieving the *n*th folder is simply not possible in a flexible way with the script at hand as you'd need to define another variable (say `bl3`, `bl4`,..., `bln`) in the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, the latest folder is already available in variable `bl1`; add echo `%bl1%` at the end before `endlocal` to display it. Retrieving the *n*th folder is simply not possible in a flexible way with that script as you would need to define another variable (say `bl3`, `bl4`,..., `bl`*`n`*) within the loop.

However, you could reverse the sort order of the output of the `dir` command by changing the `/O` option, so it returns the latest (most recent) item first. Then let an index number count the iterations of the loop, and if that index equals the predefined number *n*, store the currently iterated item:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define N here to get Nth-latest folder:
set /A LATEST=2

set /A INDEX=0
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%# in ('dir /B /A:D /O:-D "C:\somewhere"') do (
    set /A INDEX+=1
    if !INDEX! EQU !LATEST! (
        set "ITEM=%%#"
    )
)
if defined ITEM echo %LATEST%th-latest folder: %ITEM%

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

#### Update

Here is a modified script with the following improvements:

- Exclamation marks `!` in folder names are no longer lost due to toggling delayed expansion;
- the target directory can be provided as the first command line argument; if omitted, the current directory is used;
- the number *n* can be given as the second command line argument; if omitted, the user is prompted for it (this addresses [elzooilogico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6404553/elzooilogico)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986677/second-latest-folder-in-a-directory/37987943#comment63434957_37987943)); *n* defaults to `1` for empty input;
- the display output is improved to avoid something weird like `1th-latest`, `2th-latest` and `3th-latest`; instead, `The latest`, `2nd-latest` and `3rd-latest` is returned, respectively;

So this is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* define location path and folder pattern as 1st command line argument;
rem /* Define number N as 2nd command line argument to get Nth-latest folder. */

set "LATEST=%~2"
set /A LATEST+=0
if %LATEST% LEQ 0 (set /P LATEST="Enter N [1]: " & set /A LATEST+=0)
if %LATEST% LEQ 0 set /A LATEST=1
set /A INDEX=0
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%# in ('dir /B /A:D /O:-D "%~1"') do (
    set /A INDEX+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !INDEX! EQU !LATEST! (
        endlocal
        set "ITEM=%%#"
        goto :SKIP & rem // break loop after having retrieved Nth-latest folder;
    ) else endlocal
)
:SKIP
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined ITEM (
    if %LATEST% EQU 1 (echo The latest file: !ITEM!) else (
    if %LATEST% EQU 2 (echo 2nd-latest file: !ITEM!) else (
    if %LATEST% EQU 3 (echo 3rd-latest file: !ITEM!) else (
    echo %LATEST%th-latest file: !ITEM!)))
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

To achieve a similar result as with the simple script on top of this answer, you need to call this script by the following command line, supposing it has been saved as `Nth-latest.bat`:

```
Nth-latest.bat "C:\somewhere" 2
```

Comment: Aschipfl i tried your code but rather than giving me the folder names, its giving me file names. I only want it to display folder names. I'm using Command Prompt on a Windows 7 Machine.

Comment: I removed the the " - " from /A: -D so now I'm getting the proper result. Thanks a lot. I had one query regarding the eol=| used. Could you tell me whats the purpose of this?

Comment: Okay, I fixed the issue with files/folders -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37987943/2) (I just took the `dir` command line from your question where you specified `/A:-D` too). The `eol=|` overrides the default `eol` which is the semicolon, because files and folders may begin with `;`, but they cannot contain `|` (forbidden character for file/folder names)...

Comment: as suggested by @aschipfl I've removed the answer

and, continuing his/her answer, you may change

`set /A LATEST=2`

by

`echo/`

`echo/ Write 1 to get latest, 2 to get the second latest, 3 the third ans so on`

`echo/`

`set/P LATEST="-> How many do you want to skip: "`

`echo/`

Comment: Aschipfl your code is exactly what i needed. There is one issue that i came across. My "C:\somewhere" is actually a folder where there are folders whose names start with 5.9.something and rarely there are folders that have a different name altogether. I only want this script to consider folders whose names start with 5.9 and ignore other folders. For example if latest folder name is Fld1, second latest folder name is 5.9.123 and third latest folder name is 5.9.232 then the batch file should return 5.9.232 as the result since we are ignoring the folder names that dont start with 5.9

Comment: Then use command line `Nth-latest.bat "C:\somewhere\5.9.*" 2` for the second script...

Comment: Thank you aschipfl